# Error in DataTable row deletion

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

i have a datatable say DT having 11rows and i tried to delete  rows having id=3 using

```
string DeptID ="3";
string s = "id='" + DeptID + "'";
rows = DT.Select(s);
foreach (DataRow r in rows)
r.Delete();
```

i am having 5 rows having id=3 but after deletion the number of rows in datatable not changed and some red color symbol comes in each fields(columns) of the deleted rows.Can anyone know why this is happening?

and whenever i tried to acces the remaining rows using

```
     for(int i=0;i<dt1.Rows.Count;i++)
      {
      if (dt1.Rows[i][0].ToString() == "")
        {
        }
      }
```

it shows error 'deleted rows cannot take'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714171/accessing-deleted-rows-from-a-datatable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After deleting the rows,please give Acceptchanges() to the datatable,so that,it will get synchronized with new data.

```
dt.AcceptChanges();
//And u can also add a condition,while fetching the data,
foreach (DataRow dr in rows)
{  if(dr.RowState!=DataRowState.Deleted ||dr.RowState!=DataRowState.Detached)
{
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You marked the row for deletion, that's why the red color symbols appear. `row.Delete()` only changes your row state to Deleted. When you accept then changes (via `AcceptChanges` method), the actual deletion will occur.

For more information, these are some msdn links:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03c7a3zb.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.delete.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.acceptchanges.aspx