# Exception after removing Row from DataSet

Tags: c#, datagridview, strongly-typed-dataset

My Basci setting:
DataSet with 3 DataTables, no relations;
2 DataBindings one for the Version-table and on for the Script-table
2 Datagridviews which have the databindings as datasources

On a button-click-event i get the first selected row in the Version-datagridview, get the DataboundItem and cast it as "VersionRow". Then get the row in the dataset and use `Delete();` -methode.

This all runs without exceptions at all, and in Debug you see that the state of the versionrow in the dataset is changed as well. But then it's crashing with a DeletedRowInaccessibleException.

ClickEvent with Deleting:

```
private void VersionDel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (VersionDataGird.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            var x = (MainDB.VersionsRow)VersionDataGird.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem;
            mainDB.Versions.FindByID(x.ID).Delete(); 
        }

    }//after here it jumps in a generated function to get id from dataset and fails
```

I expected that the row only would disappear at the DataGridView when I delete it at DataSet. Do you know where my mistake is?

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714171/accessing-deleted-rows-from-a-datatable  Not enough in your posted code to say what you should do, nor is your intent clear, but it should give you some clues.

Comment: First Thanks for your reply :) My intent was to delete the selected row of a datagridview by delete this row from the underlying datatable. And this works also fine, **but**  after that the datagrid runs a request on the datatable and fails with the error described above. The request happens direct after the delete-methode finished.

Comment: Not clear from your code what mainDB.Versions.FindByID(x.ID).Delete(); does. Remember you are using a disconnected dataset. It's populated with data on fill, you do CRUD ops on it and then call applychanges to 'save' those changes to the db. It would appear that your dataset and db are out of synch, but your code is assuming that all is good.

Comment: Sorry my mistake: the Dataset is a "stand-alone" there's no database behind it's only loaded and saved local as xml.

Comment: We are talking past each other, DeletedRowInaccessibleExcpetion means somewhere else in your code you are trying to access the row you deleted. Are you calling applychanges anywhere?

Comment: Yes i applied it direct after the delete-methode now, and it works. The access you mentioned happens form the versiondatagrid on ?refreshing? i guess after the  row was deleted.

Comment: Have a read up about disconnected datasets in .net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are getting the Selected Row and deleting it from the database. But you are not updating the Grid View.

Try to remove the datasource of the Data Grid once you are deleting the row and after deleting the row add the data source to this grid once again.

You can also use adapter instead of this. here is a link to [tutorial](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_data/datagrid/article.php/c13041/Add-Edit-and-Delete-in-DataGridView.htm) I found in the Internet.

Hope it helps !

Comment: the resetting of the datasource and member works, but i don't understand why the datagrid isn't updating on it's databinding since i haven't a database, only a dataset which is locally loaded from a xml O.o

Comment: Arun G Whole point of the tech is so it doesn't matter how the data is physically stored. If you delete from the dataset, but don't call apply changes, it hasn't been deleted from your file, it's been marked as deleted in your dataset.